# mkdir() in php is not setting the folder permission to 0777

Tags: php, mkdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code mkdir('images','0777') creates a folder with 411 permissions! Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251283/php-code-mkdirimages-0777-creates-a-folder-with-411-permissions-why)

I am trying to create a folder on my server using php i have been trying this and it is not working it set it to 411 does anyone know why this is happening?

```
mkdir($create_path, "0777");
```

i have also tryed chmod but i am getting a safe mode error.

```
chmod($create_path, '0777');
```

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061224/php-mkdir-and-fopen-does-not-work-permissions-problem-umask-problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061224/php-mkdir-and-fopen-does-not-work-permissions-problem-umask-problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061224/php-mkdir-and-fopen-does-not-work-permissions-problem-umask-problem and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both chmod() and mkdir() accept an integer for $mode. It is easier to use octal numbers in that case:

```
mkdir('/path', 0777); // using octal
mkdir('/path', 511);  // same thing as previous but using decimal
```

Be careful and make sure you prepend your mode (i.e.: 777) with a 0 to tell the parser to use octal. Omitting the 0 will make it use decimal and will give a different result.

Since '0777' (string) is converted to decimal 777, it is not the same mode as 0777.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter should be integer as you can see [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) so use this one

> mkdir($create_path, 0777);
>   // it should works!